# WGS84 to EPSG:20007, Pulkovo 1995/ Gauss Kruger zone 7

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

I have a shapefile drawn in Selected CRS EPSG 84, when I try to load it in my project in Pulkovo 1995/ Gauss Kruger zone 7, its missplaced, and when i change shapefiles crs in properties, still no change.

im using qgis 2.18.3

Comment: Check the +wgs84 parameter in the 20007 definition. See if it's there at all, and if it is, does it match the [EPSG Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) values for 5043

Answer (score 1):

You can try in OSGeo4W Shell

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" input.shp output.shp -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:20007"
```